# IMG tag sizes attr not being used

Tags: html

Ok, what am I missing here...

I'm trying to get an image tag to start with the 250px wide "small" image, and then have the browser choose the most appropriate image based on the `srcset` & `sizes` attributes - so, you know, "normal".

**What is happening**

The `src` is the only thing used. Be it set to `superawesomeimagename 250.jpg` or `superawesomeimagename 1000.jpg` - it doesn't change/load a different image.

**The HTML Tag itself**

```
<img
    class="img-left"
    data-sizes="250,500,750,1000,1250"
    style="width:869px;max-height:580px;"
    sizes="(min-width: 869px) 72vw, 100vw"
    srcset="
        /img/superawesomeimagename 250.jpg 250w, 
        /img/superawesomeimagename 500.jpg 500w, 
        /img/superawesomeimagename 750.jpg 750w, 
        /img/superawesomeimagename 1000.jpg 1000w, 
        /img/superawesomeimagename 1250.jpg 1250w
    " 
    src="/img/superawesomeimagename_250.jpg" 
    alt="Image Alt Description"
>
```

*(Formatted for your convenience)*

I've tried

- putting `src` first (which I didn't think would make any difference, but nothing else worked)
- moving the width/height attrs set by TinyMCE into style
- removing the styles entirely
- removing the `sizes` entirely (why not)

**Extra Info**

- `data-sizes` is just there for something I am/was planning
- Not that it matters, but it's all on one line
- the 869px & 72vw are formulaic based on their design view in TinyMCE & expected admin viewing at full width.

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the reason that it wasn't working was that my test case had an un-URL-encoded space in the name. And a space denotes the gap between file name and the size.

HTML Validating saves lives.